# How to manipulate a hand?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, distort

I've got this picture I'm making as a joke for my friends and I to 'ave a giggle about, and I've run into a snag.
[image]

His hand does not work with the ledge, probably because it wasn't originally a ledge:
[image]

I'de like to puppet the hand or something to straigten it out so it is spread out on the surface, not crunched like it is. I've tried using puppet editing, but whenever I use that it always seems like his finger is skinny and boney by then end. I don't know quite what to do.

[Link to the .PSD](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzgDIjhDOu6EY2NDX3ozWVRLTUU)

Comment: I'd try to hide ... Like, Put the "3" character on it or some text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, the most basic thing that integrates an object with a near surface is shadow.

So, put a shadow according to the lighting situation. You can basicly:

- Copy the hand, put it below the original one
- Make it black using curves
- Use multiply as the blending mode
- Difuse it (acording to the original light, use the original photo as a reference)
- Play with the opacity
- In some cases you need to distort to match some perspective, (but probably not necessary on this case)

Other factors are proportion, color grading, light angle but they looks ok on your image.

One aditional thing. Move a bit the guy away from the near edge of the wall. See where it inersects on the original photo, almost next to the border of the arm. On your composition the guy is floating over the edge.

If it affects a lot at the composition, I would cut the wall as a new object and move it to the right and up.